# How to write Javascript strings into StringBuilder in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, string

I have some `javascript` code written on top of c# with `string builder` like following:

```
StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
```

How to write these two lines without any syntax error, I am facing problems with writing those lines:

```
cstext.Append("data.setFormattedValue(row, 0, data.getFormattedValue(row, 0).replace(/src=".*"/i, 'src="' + src + '"'));");
```

(Error here is in this part `(/src=".*"/i, 'src="' + src + '"'));`)

and

`cstext.Append("if(childrenOfChildren == "")");`

(Error is here `== ""` its facing conflicts with other `""`)

Sorry for this non understand question but I can't explain better. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace the double quotes with escaped doubles quotes :

```
StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
cstext.Append("data.setFormattedValue(row, 0, data.getFormattedValue(row, 0).replace(/src=".*"/i, 'src=\"' + src + '\"'));");
cstext.Append("if(childrenOfChildren == \"\")");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use escape char `\`

```
cstext.Append("data.setFormattedValue(row, 0, data.getFormattedValue(row, 0).replace(/src=\".*\"/i, 'src=\"' + src + '\"'));");
```

And

```
cstext.Append("if(childrenOfChildren == \"\")");
```